# How to get a cell value from an html table to use in an axios request in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a HTML table of clients, and I want to be able to delete one of them thanks to a simple axios delete request. In order to do that, I have to get the ID of the client I want to delete.
So here is what I did :

```
  async function deleteClient(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = document.getElementById("client").innerHTML;

    console.log(id);

    axios
      .delete("http://localhost:8080/api/clients/" + id)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }); 
  }
```

The deleteClient function is called onClick in the table. The issue is, it only ever gets the ID of the first row client and never the one from rows below. What can I do to get the right ID and be able to delete other clients ?

For info, here is my HTML table, it is filled dynamically thanks to useEffect hook and a simple axios get request :

```
 <table className="text-white border-2 border-bikeexplogray-light rounded-full">
          <tr>
            <th>Clients</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Store Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone number</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Zipcode</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Website</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>{" "}
          {filteredData.map((value, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={value.id}>
                <td id="client">{value.id}</td>
                <td>{value.storeName}</td>
                <td>{value.username}</td>
                <td>{value.email}</td>
                <td>{value.phone}</td>
                <td>{value.adress}</td>
                <td>{value.zipcode}</td>
                <td>{value.city}</td>
                <td>{value.website}</td>
                <td>
                  <button onClick={deleteClient}>Delete</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This is React. You're not supposed to use `document.*` functions. Use `onClick={e => deleteClient(e, id)}` and now you can use `function deleteClient(e, id)` to simply pass it along. Also note that unless that table is inside a <form>, you don't need to preventDefault(). Finally, you'll probably also want to update the client-side table, i.e. remove the row from the data array.

Comment: Also note that in general, having more than one element with `<td id="client">` is already nonsense, because an `id` is supposed to be unique. Why would `document.getElementById("client")` conveniently grab the correct element out of dozens? Makes no sense and is therefore not how it works.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answers and the advice. I am only a beginner. Apologies if my question was dumb or unclear. Thanks anyways, I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get the id of the customer you want to delete because you are in a `map()` function. Each one of your rows have a unical `key` that is equal to `value.id`, so you can modify the button as follows to do the trick :

```
<button onClick={(e) => deleteClient(e, value.id)}>Delete</button>
```

And don't forget to modify your `deleteClient` function :

```
async function deleteClient(e, id) {


e.preventDefault();
    //const id = document.getElementById("client").innerHTML;

    console.log(id);

    axios
      .delete("http://localhost:8080/api/clients/" + id)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }); 
  }
```

Comment: This is a worse pattern to follow because you are needlessly generating unique event handlers that you will be rebinding on every render.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren Unless of course you're using React, in which case this is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: @ChrisG correct way? It's a convenient way but it has drawbacks. It in case OP already has a generic event handler for the delete event, he's already set it up then why not build it that way? It's more performant.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren As soon as performance becomes an issue, OP might want to look into that. Until then they should learn how to write proper React code first and foremost, is my view here.

Comment: @ChrisG why form a bad habit, it's not really more or less difficult to do either way. It's not like "React" is somehow divorced from how the DOM works. Understanding this relationship is equally important. I'd leave it to OP to make up their own mind about this.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren I disagree wholeheartedly; OP needs to learn the React way of doing things (i.e. no longer referencing the DOM directly). Months from now, when they have mastered React basics, there's plenty of time to diverge from that when performance should ever become an issue. And as you say, it's not really difficult, so there's no good reason to learn it now.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute on the `td` tag must be unique within the document.

You can use `data-id` instead, `data-*` is just a standard way to attach data to the DOM.

In your event handler `deleteClient` you can use `e.currentTarget` to access the context.

```js
function deleteClient(e) {
  // this will be your button element
  const button = e.currentTarget
  
  // search up the DOM tree (each parent) for this selector match
  const td = button.closest("tr > td[data-id]")

  // this should be the ID from the data-* attribute
  console.log(td.dataset.id) 

  // ...
}
```

Comment: OP is using React. This is good advice for vanilla JS, not for React though.

Comment: @ChrisG this is good advice regardless.